# What can I say about a map multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, cyclic-groups, inverse-function

If I know the following:

If I have the following homomorphism $f: \mathbb Z_{p^a} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{p^b}$ defined by multiplication by $n/d$ where $n = p^b$ and $d = \gcd(p^a, p^b).$

And I know the following:

1. if $a\geq b$ then $f$ is onto.
2. if $a \leq b$ then $f$ is 1-1.

How can I use this piece of information to conclude something about this function: multiplication by $rn/d$ for $r= p^t x$ and $0 \leq r < d$? when is this map 1-1 and when it is onto?

Could anyone help me in that please?

**Is this map trivially onto?**

Comment: To be clear, what is your definition of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$ for some positive integer $n?$

Comment: On second thought, I assume that you are considering these as abelian groups and not rings; otherwise, multiplication is not a homomorphism (e.g., we have that $f(4) = 4n/d \neq 4n^2/d^2 = f(2)f(2)$ so that $f$ is not a ring homomorphism).

Comment: Yes I am considering $\mathbb Z_n$ abelian groups @Carlo

Comment: @Confusion This will fall into the category of ''nitpicking with the details'', but "quotient-spaces'' is *not* an appropriate tag here. That tag refers to either *topological* or *vector* spaces, and there is barely any such thing in sight, within the entire context of this purely group/number-theoretical problem.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ ok I will correct my tags .... thanks for clarification!

Comment: ok thank you! I will read your answer now and ask if I do not understand anything (if you do not mind).@ΑΘΩ

Comment: @Confusion But of course, I would be glad to know the answer served in helping you better understand the matter. Therefore do not hesitate to ask〜

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us handle the natural generalisation of the problem you present. Consider $m, n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$ together with the notation $\mathbb{Z}_r\colon=\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ for any $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $d\colon=(m; n)$ denote the greatest common divisor of the two numbers and also consider $m'\colon=\frac{m}{d}, n'=\frac{n}{d}$ (the fractions exist since $d \neq 0$).

Let us fix $k \in \mathbb{N}^{\times} \cap n'\mathbb{Z}$ and let $f \in \mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the additive group endomorphism given by $f(r)=kr$ for arbitrary $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is obvious that $f[m\mathbb{Z}]=f\left[\langle m \rangle\right]=\left\langle f(m)\right\rangle \leqslant n\mathbb{Z}$, since $f(m)=mk \in mn'\mathbb{Z}=m'dn'\mathbb{Z}=m'n\mathbb{Z} \leqslant n\mathbb{Z}$, which means that $f$ induces a *quotient* morphism $g \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}\left(\mathbb{Z}_m, \mathbb{Z}_n\right)$, described by $g\left(\overline{r}\right)=\widehat{f(r)}=\widehat{kr}$, where $\overline{\bullet}$ denotes classes modulo $m$ respectively $\widehat{\bullet}$ refers to classes modulo $n$.

By virtue of the general properties of quotient morphisms, we have $\mathrm{Ker}g=f^{-1}\left[n\mathbb{Z}\right]/m\mathbb{Z}$. It is easy to see that $f^{-1}\left[n\mathbb{Z}\right]=\frac{n}{(k; n)}\mathbb{Z}$, whence $\mathrm{Ker}g=\frac{n}{(k; n)}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \approx \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{m(k;n)}{n}} \ (\mathbf{Gr})$. In particular, $g$ is injective if and only if $\frac{m(k; n)}{n}=1$, relation equivalently expressed as $m(k; n)=n \Leftrightarrow m \mid n \wedge (k; n)=\frac{n}{m}$.

As to the image, we have that $\mathrm{Im}g=\left(\mathrm{Im}f+n\mathbb{Z}\right)/n\mathbb{Z}=\left(k\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}\right)/n\mathbb{Z}=(k; n)\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\frac{n}{(k; n)}\mathbb{Z} \ (\mathbf{Gr})$. Therefore, $g$ is surjective if and only if $(k; n)=1$, which entails $n'=1$ and thus $n \mid m$. The surjectivity of $g$ is thus attained if and only if $n \mid m$ and $(k; n)=1$.

---

**P.S.** On the existence and properties of quotient morphisms in the category (context) of groups. I won't fully go into details by proving the statements below (we could do this at a later time, as I confess I currently don't have too much time to spare in order to be active on this forum).

> **Proposition 1.** Let $f \colon G \to G'$ and $g \colon G \to G''$ two group morphisms such that $g$ is *surjective* and $\mathrm{Ker}g \leqslant \mathrm{Ker}f$. Then there exists a *unique* group morphism $h \colon G'' \to G'$ such that $f=h \circ g$ (in other words, the diagram below is *commutative*). We refer to $h$ as the quotient of $f$ with respect to $g$. We have the following descriptions:
> $$\begin{align}
> \mathrm{Ker}h&=g\left[\mathrm{Ker}f\right]\\
> \mathrm{Im}h&=\mathrm{Im}f.
> \end{align}$$

[image]

> **Proposition 2** (particular case of the previous). For arbitrary group $G$ and normal subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$ we adopt the notation $\sigma^G_H \colon G \to G/H$ to refer to the canonical surjection associated to the quotient by $H$. Let $f \colon G \to G'$ be a group morphism together with two *normal* subgroups $H \trianglelefteq G$ and $H' \trianglelefteq G'$ such that $f[H] \leqslant H'$ (which is equivalent to $H \leqslant f^{-1}\left[H'\right]$). Then there exists a *unique* morphism $g \colon G/H \to G'/H'$ such that $\sigma^{G'}_{H'} \circ f=g \circ \sigma^G_H$ (in other words, the diagram below is again *commutative*). We have the descriptions:
> $$\begin{align}
> \mathrm{Ker}g&=f^{-1}\left[H'\right]/H\\
> \mathrm{Im}g&=\sigma^{G'}_{H'}\left[\mathrm{Im}f\right]=\left(H'\mathrm{Im}f\right)/H'.
> \end{align}$$

[image]

Proposition 2 is obtained from proposition 1 by considering $\sigma^{G'}_{H'} \circ f$ in the role of the original $f$ and $\sigma^G_H$ in the role of the original $g$.

Comment: why you are taking $k$ specifically in that domain "Let us fix $k \in \mathbb{N}^{\times} \cap n'\mathbb{Z}$"? specifically why not $m'$?

Comment: @Confusion Any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ induces an endomorphism (the homothety of scalar $k$ with respect to the $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure of $\mathbb{Z}$) however only those in the specific domain $n'\mathbb{Z}$ have the property of inducing an endomorphism which maps $m\mathbb{Z}$ to $n\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, the condition is required to even have an induced quotient morphism (and the limitation to strictly positive naturals is just for convenience).

Comment: what is "homothety"?

Comment: @Confusion It is special terminology used in the theory of modules, so if you haven't been exposed to it yet perhaps you don't need to worry about it. In this specific context, I mean to refer to the endomorphism of "multiplying by $k$".

Comment: I will go to sleep now for about 4 hours as I am very tired then I will come back to your answer to read it thoroughly. Thanks for your keen help! and good night

Comment: @Confusion Don't mention it! Sad to hear that you can only enjoy 4 hrs. of rest (it wouldn't be enough for a good night's rest, I believe...). Let me know of any new questions after you wake up.

Comment: In your paragraph before last. what are the general properties of the quotient morphism?

Comment: I do not understand why "$f^{-1}\left[n\mathbb{Z}\right]=\frac{n}{(k; n)}\mathbb{Z}$" could you please explain that ?

Comment: I did not get why "$g$ is injective if and only if $\frac{m(k; n)}{n}=1$" could you please explain more?

Comment: why image $g$ looks like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116908/discussion-between--and-confusion).